# Where should I put a custom class file in zend framework 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php, zend-framework3

I have created a set of class files that helps to create the route configuration array. I, however, do not know where to put the source files. I browsed around a little and found some answers that suggested I put up the code in packagist and install it via composer, but my classes are relatively small. So, I wanted to ask if there is another way to do it. The files must be accessible in all the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application code is organised into modules and lives in `module/<Modulename>/src/`. If the code is something you might want to reuse in other applications, then it might make more sense to have it as a standalone library that you install via. Composer.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I got everywhere else. I was asking if there is another way to get the same result. But I guess I will have to use composer for it. Makes sense as I need them in other applications too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're code is accessibly through all the application if it is configured in the composer.json's autoload section.

Code structure in ZF is quite simple. You have your modules and in every module you have an src directory. This src directory should have its own namespace. And there you can place your custom route configurator under this namespace, like 'ModuleName\RouteConfigurator'.

But if you use this logic through multiple modules, I suggest you to create a separate module for it. In this case, after a long road, you may consider creating a separate composer package from it. But it's not necessary.

If you're not familiar with defining modules, please read the zend-modulemanager's documentation (https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-modulemanager/intro/)

Comment: I am thinking of creating a composer package and using it. Thank you, I have upvoted you but since my rep is below 15, well you get the point. Thanks anyway.